# How do I start a screen session using an upstart job with a non privileged user?

Tags: gnu-screen, startup, upstart

I am trying to create an Upstart job that starts a new `screen` session on boot, in which I would like to automatically start a `java` executable.  Here is the .conf file I am currently trying to get to work, although I have tried several others:

```
description     "Run the bungeecord jar"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0 and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]

exec start-stop-daemon --start -c ridog --exec /usr/bin/screen -- -dmUS BungeeCord java -server -XX:UseSSE=4 -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:MaxPermSize=356m -XX:ParallelGCThreads=6 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Xmx256M -jar BungeeCord.jar

pre-stop script
    screen -S BungeeCord -X foo "end^M"
end script
```

To my knowledge, the script seems to work fine, I can run `sudo start bungeecord` and get the intended result, however, restarting the machine does not work.  Instead, I get this error in the `/var/log/upstart/bungeecord.log`:

```
Cannot make directory '/var/run/screen': Permission denied
```

I've looked up this error and the search results are obscure and inconclusive. I've tried running the command as root, this removes the error but still no `screen` session.  I've tried different commands like this:

```
su ridog -c "screen -dmS BungeeCord java -jar /home/ridog/BungeeCord/BungeeCord.jar"
```

Comment: How are you sure that the `screen` session isn't started as `root`? Please start a program in `screen` that way that cannot fail (like `sleep 1000`).

Comment: No luck using the command `screen -dmS test sleep 1000`.  No screen sockets running in both the root account and my own upon reboot.  However, no errors in the log.

Comment: If I execute `screen -dmS test sleep 1000` via `crontab` then there is the expected screen session. Trying with `cron` may be easier for you anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Problem solved**, I switched from using `upstart` to using `cron`.  It was much more simple and everything works great now.

For anyone reading this that might be curious as to how I did it, I made a simple `shell script`:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -Xms256M -Xmx256M -jar /home/ridog/BungeeCord/BungeeCord.jar
```

And set it to run on startup with a new line in `crontab -e`:

```
@reboot screen -dmS BungeeCord sh /home/ridog/BungeeCord/run.sh
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: this does not work if your drive is mounted after the system boots.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/screen/+bug/1380080 is a regression report. It has stopped working for me on 14.04

Answer (score 4):

Invoking screen via upstart is indeed somewhat tricky. The first problem regarding non-existing `/var/run/screen` can be easily solved though.

On Ubuntu 10.10 to 13.10 there is an upstart task which is responsible for cleaning up and (re-)creating `/var/run/screen` on bootup so you need to make sure your upstart script will run after it:

```
start on stopped screen-cleanup
```

On Ubuntu 10.04 and earlier as well as Ubuntu 14.04 and later that code is in the init script `/etc/init.d/screen-cleanup` which means upstart jobs can refer to it as the result of `rc`:

```
start on stopped rc
```

However, screen will probably still complain about /var/run/screen permissions. This can be workarounded by invoking screen via setsid:

```
exec setsid screen -Dm /some/command
```

Your screen session will fork once, so you need to add the "expect fork" stanza to make sure upstart follows the correct pid.

Here's a complete example script (needs at least Ubuntu 12.04):

```
# screen startup script
# requires upstart v1.4 or newer

description "running top in screen session"

start on ( local-filesystems
           and stopped rc )
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

setuid test
setgid test

# "setsid screen -Dm" only forks once
expect fork

# use setsid to avoid screen complaining about /var/run/screen permissions.
exec setsid screen -Dm -S mytopsession /usr/bin/top
```

Comment: Doesn't the last line of the example script start an useless instance of `top` ? Is it necessary to launch it even if the program itself won't be used ?

Comment: You need to replace top with whatever application you want to run inside your screen session of course. I only used top for the example because it's well-known and available on most systems.

Answer (score -1):

Create `/var/run/screen` as `root` with the appropriate permissions before you make the `screen` call.