# View console output from an Upstart job without logfiles

Tags: output, upstart

I wrote a custom Java server. I am running it using Upstart (`/etc/init/myservice.config`) where I launch `java -jar myservice.jar`.

The java process uses `System.out.println` to write log messages of all kinds.

I want to be able to connect to it from a remote ssh session and view the output.

**UPDATE: I want to do this without the hassle of creating, rotating, managing log files.**

I've looked at a number of posts, including:
[How to view the output of a running process in another bash session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58550/how-to-view-the-output-of-a-running-process-in-another-bash-session)

I've tried `cat` and `tail -f /proc/<procid>/fd/0 /proc/<procid>/fd/1 /proc/<procid>/fd/2` — all are blank output.

All this is as root

I know there are more things to try, but I'm suspicious since the fd's are blank (or at least for me).

Im running Ubunutu Server 14.04 LTS, Oracle Java 8

Update:
Looking to try screen, but I see its not exactly meant for this...
[How do I start a screen session using an upstart job with a non privileged user?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138833/how-do-i-start-a-screen-session-using-an-upstart-job-with-a-non-privileged-user)

Comment: Why arent you using log4j or one of Java's libraries for logging? These types of libraries will log output to a txt or log file that you can tail. A system.out.println statement will NOT write to a log file..

Comment: @ryekayo- i appreciate your indirect suggestion.  log4j is an enormous PIA, especially with its newer version and the conflicting documentation.
In a more direct answer, its because this is how it is written today, and I need a fast way to connect to it, rather than rewriting my app.  Maybe one day I will.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to redirect the output to a file like this:

```
java -jar myservice.jar >> /var/tmp/myservice
```

If there's a lot of output, the log can grow big, so you may want to trim it with a `cron` task every few hours or so, or to rotate logs.

Make sure it is `System.out.println` that prints the output, not `System.err.println`. If it's `err`, you need to redirect the error stream.

```
java -jar myservice.jar 2>> /var/tmp/myservice
```

Comment: yes, the log will get big... but perhaps this is good enough for now, before i can implement something more robust in the code itself.  I think maybe i can use this in conjunction with rotatelogs...

Comment: You can put rotation in `cron`, in case it's not so readable in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
java -jar myservice.jar > mylogfile.txt 2>&1
```

The `2>&1` means that you also log the errors from your program into `mylogfile.txt`